# How to get the return value of instruments?

Tags: ios, macos, bash, teamcity, instruments

I'm using instruments inside a bash script on a continuous integration server.

I would like to know when a command as failed in the script, so I can exit prematurely from it and mark the build as failed.

instruments displays a LOG ERROR to the console, but I don't succeed in getting a return value.

How can I achieve this?

if have:

```
instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.3 Simulator)" -t
```

it is possible to do something like:

```
if(...)
then ...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So `instruments` doesn't set an exit code?

Comment: i don't know. If yes how can i get it?

Comment: Well I think you need to read about evaluating process exit codes within the shell.  After that the solution is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly easy:

```
instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.3 Simulator)" -t
if (( $? > 0 ))
then
    echo "instruments commands failed with error: $?" >&2
fi
```

The `(( ))` notation is for an arithmetic comparison.  String pattern comparisons are done using `[[ ... ]]`.  Be careful to use the correct spacing, in general whitespace is used as a separator in shells, so it can be significant.

An alternative syntax could be:

```
if instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.3 Simulator)" -t
then
    echo "it worked"
else
    echo "it failed"
fi
```

and that is often preferable.  But I think in this case the style I show fits better with what you need.

The special variable `?` gives the return value of the previous command.  Prefixing with a `$` gives us the variable's value.  By convention, a return value of zero means success, 1-255 means an error (the range on UNIX/Linux is 0-255, one byte).  The significance of each error number is application specific, so you must read the documentation to find what it means.

Remember that `$?` gives us the return value of the *previous* command, so even an `echo` would reset it!

The `>&2` means "send the output to the standard error stream".  Error messages should go here, which is also known s stderr, file descriptor 2.  It is a nice thing to do if you are redirecting output from the script.

EDIT:  After all that, Apple does not appear to document an exit code for the `instruments` command, I checked the `man` page.  That's poor in my opinion, but there's not much you can do.  In languages like C (and probably ObjC) if the program ends without setting an exit code you just get any old value that is lying about in memory.  So you cannot even rely on zero being success - unless you know otherwise?